# HDFS as volume in cloudera quickstart docker

Tags: hadoop, docker, hdfs, cloudera, bigdata

I am fairly new to both hadoop and docker.

I haven been working on extending the cloudera/quickstart docker image docker file and wanted to mount a directory form host and map it to hdfs location, so that performance is increased and data are persist localy.

When i mount volume anywhere with `-v /localdir:/someDir` everything works fine, but that's not my goal. But when i do `-v /localdir:/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs` both datanode and namenode fails to start and I get : "cd /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs: Permission denied". And when i do `-v /localdir:/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache` no permission denied but datanode and namenode, or one of them fails to start on starting the docker image and i can't find any useful information in log files about the reason for that.

Mayby someone came across this problem, or have some other solution for putting hdfs outside the docker container?

Comment: Have you checked the docker logs (`docker logs <ID>`) for the container?

Comment: Yeah, as i edited my post:
1) When using '-v /localdir:/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs' get:
starting datanode, logging to /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-quickstart.cloudera.out
Failed to start Hadoop datanode. Return value: 1
bash: line 0: cd: /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs: Permission denied
Failed to start Hadoop journalnode. Return value: 3
bash: line 0: cd: /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs: Permission denied
Failed to start Hadoop namenode. Return value: 3
bash: line 0: cd: /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs: Permission denied
Failed to start Hadoop secondarynamenode. Return value: 3

Comment: 2) and when using  '-v /localdir:/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache' get:
starting datanode, logging to /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-quickstart.cloudera.out
Failed to start Hadoop datanode. Return value: 1
starting journalnode, logging to /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-journalnode-quickstart.cloudera.out
Started Hadoop journalnode:OK 
starting namenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-quickstart.cloudera.out
Failed to start Hadoop namenode. Return value: 1
And the same with secondary namenode

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem and I've managed the situation copying the entire `/var/lib` directory from container to a local directory

From terminal, start the `cloudera/quickstart` container without start all hadoop services:

```
docker run -ti cloudera/quickstart /bin/bash
```

In another terminal [copy the container directory to the local directory](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)
:

```
mkdir /local_var_lib
docker exec your_container_id tar Ccf $(dirname /var/lib) - $(basename /var/lib) | tar Cxf /local_var_lib -
```

After all files copied from container to local dir, stop the container and point the `/var/lib` to the new target. Make sure the `/local_var_lib` directory contains the hadoop directories (hbase, hadoop-hdfs, oozie, mysql, etc).

Start the container:

```
docker run --name cloudera \
  --hostname=quickstart.cloudera \
  --privileged=true \
  -td \
  -p 2181:2181 \
  -p 8888:8888 \
  -p 7180:7180 \
  -p 6680:80 \
  -p 7187:7187 \
  -p 8079:8079 \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -p 8085:8085 \
  -p 8400:8400 \
  -p 8161:8161 \
  -p 9090:9090 \
  -p 9095:9095 \
  -p 60000:60000 \
  -p 60010:60010 \
  -p 60020:60020 \
  -p 60030:60030 \
  -v /local_var_lib:/var/lib \
  cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

Answer (score 1):

You should run a

```
docker exec -it "YOUR CLOUDERA CONTAINER" chown -R hdfs:hadoop /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/
```