# keep CDH container running

Tags: docker, containers, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I am learning CDH and Docker and didn't have prior experiene in setting up both tools. After reading documentation i managed to run CDH docker in mac environment and also completed example given in quick start guid. But when next day when i started mac book again to learn something new but i didn't find my previous work which i found very strange and even couldn't see container running which seems fine to me.

What i really want to do is i don't want to loose my work even after stoping docker container. could you please guid me how do i configure docker so that i will not loose my work even after restarting docker again?

Comment: what command did you use to start your docker container?
if you run `docker ps -a`, you'll likely see your container and it's probably in exited state, so your previous work should be still in that container..

Comment: i have used following commands. 
`docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -i -t -p 8888:8888 -p 80:80 70bf9e3b8efa /usr/bin/docker-quickstart`
when i start my machine i cant see any container running.

Answer (score 0):

Every instance of a `docker run` will allocate a new filesystem, essentially starting from scratch.

If you actually want to "save" your work, then you need to volume mount (using `-v` docker flag) your local filesystem into the container for at least the following directories.

- HDFS Data Directory
- NameNode Data Directory
- `/home/cloudera`

I think the hadoop data folders are somewhere under `/var/lib/hadoop-*`, by default

---

The better alternative for saving your workloads would be the CDH VM, where it actually has a persistent HDD associated with it.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. i didn't find anything in Cloudera documentation to configure volume for datanode.

Comment: Because that's out of scope for running CDH. By using Docker, one is somewhat expected to know the intricacies that involves... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521048/hdfs-as-volume-in-cloudera-quickstart-docker

Comment: I am not using docker now and started using virtualbox.

Comment: As far as I know, the virtualbox image internally still uses Docker